# Oracle sql or pl/sql command for checking if remote database is available i.e. similar to OS command tnsping

Tags: oracle, networking, plsql, connection, tnsping

In my PL/SQL script, I have requirement to test the connectivity of remote data. Normally, in OS shell, we use command tnsping. Is there any command in SQL or PL/SQL so that I can test connectivity.

Basically, I am getting some data using database link. I want my script to execute immediately. If remote database is available then I want to run query using database link. If remote database is unavailable then I want to skip the getting of data using database link. So, this is the reason why I am looking for.

Kindly guide me for proper way. So, that my script does not hang in case of unavailability of remote database.

I am using Oracle 12.1C.

Comment: But if you can't connect, you can't run any commands. Are you talking about `sqlplus` or something else? And if `tnsping` does it, why don't you use it?

Comment: Normally, when we use database link in pl/sql code or sql query then it get data from remote database if remote database is available. But, if remote database is not available then sql query hangs ... I want to avoid hang.

Comment: And what is the method that you're running that SQL? Is it `sqlplus` or something else?

Comment: Oracle PL/SQL stored procedure ... and sql statement: ........ select column_name into v_variable from my_table@db_link

Comment: That's what you run **in** the database. But what is the **tool / programming language** you use to **connect to your database**

Comment: If you don't know even that, include the code (not just the SQL statement), but the full code you're running, and how you're running it.

Comment: @Jeer There might be a TNS setting for this. For example, find your tnsnames.ora file and add `(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=5)` should make the connection break quickly, instead of hanging forever. But I can't seem to get [CONNECT_TIMEOUT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/tnsnames.htm#NETRF666) to work for me. It might depend on exactly what the connection is waiting for.

Comment: I need something like dbms_tns.resolve_tnsname, that is available in 12.2C ... While I am using 12.1C

Comment: Yes, that's clear. Is there a reason why you're not telling what you run?

Comment: @jeer I don't think even DBMS_TNS will help you here. That package only gives you the connection string; it doesn't actually test the connection.

Comment: thanks. then what can be the solution?